# KDE Discover doesnt start up with weird error message

Tags: kde, plasma, discover-software-center

I just freshly installed Kubuntu on my Laptop and everything ran smoothly.
Then `plasma-discover` stopped working all of a sudden. When I try to start it, the Window appears for a second or so as a small rectangle in the top left corner and immediately disapperas afterwards.
Starting it from command line, gives the same result with the following message:

```
$ plasma-discover
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
qrc:/qml/DiscoverWindow.qml:116:19: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:674:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 14. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:670:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 13. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot have negative intervals
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
qrc:/qml/DiscoverPage.qml:42:37: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x55feeb4688e0)
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Couldn't find a category for  "fwupd-backend"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/PrivateActionToolButton.qml:75:5: QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"
QQuickItem::stackBefore: Cannot stack QQuickRectangle(0x55feeb88dda0, parent=0x55feeaea8fe0, geometry=0,0 0x0) before QQuickPopupItem(0x55feeb04c110), which must be a sibling
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/GlobalDrawer.qml:333:17: QML RowLayout (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "preferredHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/AbstractApplicationWindow.qml:283:5: QML Binding: Not restoring previous value because restoreMode has not been set.
This behavior is deprecated.
You have to import QtQml 2.15 after any QtQuick imports and set
the restoreMode of the binding to fix this warning.
In Qt < 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBinding.
In Qt >= 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBindingOrValue.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running the command as `root` starts the application correctly with the following message:

```
sudo plasma-discover
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qrc:/qml/DiscoverWindow.qml:116:19: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:674:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 14. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:670:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 13. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
qrc:/qml/DiscoverPage.qml:42:37: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x561aaf758820)
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Couldn't find a category for  "fwupd-backend"
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/PrivateActionToolButton.qml:75:5: QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/AbstractApplicationWindow.qml:283:5: QML Binding: Not restoring previous value because restoreMode has not been set.
This behavior is deprecated.
You have to import QtQml 2.15 after any QtQuick imports and set
the restoreMode of the binding to fix this warning.
In Qt < 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBinding.
In Qt >= 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBindingOrValue.

file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/BasicListItem.qml:273:18: QML QQuickItem*: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/AbstractApplicationWindow.qml:283:5: QML Binding: Not restoring previous value because restoreMode has not been set.
This behavior is deprecated.
You have to import QtQml 2.15 after any QtQuick imports and set
the restoreMode of the binding to fix this warning.
In Qt < 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBinding.
In Qt >= 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBindingOrValue.
```

I made some research and maybe it has something to do with some keybindings but I have no idea on how to fix that...
My `plasma-discover` version is `5.24.7` and I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 on the `6.5.0-15-generic x86_64` kernel

Running `gdb plasma-discover` results in:

```
$ gdb plasma-discover
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from plasma-discover...
(No debugging symbols found in plasma-discover)
(gdb) start
Function "main" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
Starting program: /usr/bin/plasma-discover 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff0147640 (LWP 9869)]
[New Thread 0x7fffef0d6640 (LWP 9870)]
[New Thread 0x7fffedb22640 (LWP 9871)]
[New Thread 0x7fffed321640 (LWP 9872)]
[New Thread 0x7fffecb20640 (LWP 9873)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5fff640 (LWP 9874)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe57fe640 (LWP 9875)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4ffd640 (LWP 9876)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8fff640 (LWP 9877)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbbfff640 (LWP 9878)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9879)]
[Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9879) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbbfff640 (LWP 9878) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffbbfff640 (LWP 9880)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9881)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbaffd640 (LWP 9882)]
[Thread 0x7fffbaffd640 (LWP 9882) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9881) exited]
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
qrc:/qml/DiscoverWindow.qml:116:19: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:674:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 14. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/PageRow.qml:670:5: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 13. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot have negative intervals
[New Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9883)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbaffd640 (LWP 9884)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb99e6640 (LWP 9885)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb91e5640 (LWP 9886)]
kf.config.core: "\"geometry\" - conversion of \"776,258,0,65507\" to QRect failed"
qrc:/qml/DiscoverPage.qml:42:37: QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings associated with 15. Use 'sequences: [ <key> ]' to bind to all of them.
[New Thread 0x7fffa3fff640 (LWP 9887)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa37fe640 (LWP 9888)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa2ffd640 (LWP 9889)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa27fc640 (LWP 9890)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa1ffb640 (LWP 9891)]
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x555555eec230)
[New Thread 0x7fffa17fa640 (LWP 9892)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8bfff640 (LWP 9893)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 9894]
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Couldn't find a category for  "fwupd-backend"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/PrivateActionToolButton.qml:75:5: QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"
[New Thread 0x7fff8b7fe640 (LWP 9896)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8affd640 (LWP 9897)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8a7fc640 (LWP 9898)]
QQuickItem::stackBefore: Cannot stack QQuickRectangle(0x555556312ba0, parent=0x55555592d020, geometry=0,0 0x0) before QQuickPopupItem(0x555555acfa70), which must be a sibling
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/GlobalDrawer.qml:333:17: QML RowLayout (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "preferredHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/AbstractApplicationWindow.qml:283:5: QML Binding: Not restoring previous value because restoreMode has not been set.
This behavior is deprecated.
You have to import QtQml 2.15 after any QtQuick imports and set
the restoreMode of the binding to fix this warning.
In Qt < 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBinding.
In Qt >= 6.0 the default is Binding.RestoreBindingOrValue.


Thread 1 "plasma-discover" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6ace859 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 0x7fffb91e5640 (LWP 9886) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffa3fff640 (LWP 9887) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffa17fa640 (LWP 9892) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffa27fc640 (LWP 9890) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbb7fe640 (LWP 9883) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffbaffd640 (LWP 9884) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffb99e6640 (LWP 9885) exited]

Thread 1 "plasma-discover" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6ace859 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6ace859 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#1  0x00007ffff6aeaa4e in QQmlPropertyCapture::captureProperty(QObject*, int, int, bool) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff69a78cd in QV4::QObjectWrapper::getProperty(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, QObject*, QQmlPropertyData*) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#3  0x00007fffd82c119b in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Can you attach a backtrace? Run `gdb plasma-discover`. Answer "n" at all the prompts, and type "start" when it says "(gdb)". If it says "(gdb)" after anything other than "Temporary breakpoint" or "SIGSEGV", type "c". Once it says "SIGSEGV", type "bt", and hold enter until you see "(gdb)" again. Then [edit] your post with the stacktrace

Comment: okay i hope i understood correctly what you wanted me to do, check the edited post.
when doing this, the `plasma-discover` windows also doesn't disappear but if i try to resize it (since it's very small) i get some graphics bug where the outlines of the window are moving but the content inside stays at the same place

Comment: okay i might have found a solution. as discussed [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448460) there is a fix for people that is provided [here](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/discover/-/merge_requests/228).
But unfortunately I don't really understand, how to apply that fix... Any idea?

Comment: Oh thanks for finding the solution. That patch is already in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/plasma-discover/plasma-discover_5.24.7.orig.tar.xz . If you're eager to upgrade, as a last resort you can use https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports . I was in the middle of debugging and running out of ideas. My last idea is: Does the problem go away if you delete the `~/.config/discoverrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't really know why it fixes it but I found the following solution [here](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/discover/-/commit/53b328842032c4d159f34fa330ad4f6914fd95a6).

Basically I went into the file

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/NavigationTabBar.qml
```

to `line 231` and changed the following `true` to `false`:

```
 T.ButtonGroup {
        id: tabGroup
        exclusive: true
        buttons: root.contentItem.children
```

to

```
 T.ButtonGroup {
        id: tabGroup
        exclusive: false
        buttons: root.contentItem.children
```

The explanation is:

> The actions in Kirigami.NavigationTabBar are bounded by an
> exclusive button group, which on start-up competes with the
> binding on the `checked` property within those actions.
> This results in an endless loop of alternating states,
> and eventually a crash when the QV4 heap saturates.
> Setting this group as non-exclusive fixes the issue.
> BUG: 448460 
> FIXED-IN: 5.24

What still bothers me is the fact that it should be fixed with version `5.24` and I'm running version `5.24.7`. But this solved the Issue for me

Comment: Nice find! Your merge request link is included in 5.24.7 according to the apt source, but apparently you fixed another bug!

Comment: Weirdly enough the solution still persist when I change the contents of the file from `false` back to `true`...